# SQL - Must declare the scalar variable error

Tags: sql

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my SQL code.  It says I need to declare the scalar variable @tempMile2, but it is a declared table.

```
INSERT INTO @tempMile (UserFullName, USERs_ID, timecard_date, timecard_createddate)
SELECT UserFullName, USERs_ID, timecard_date, timecard_createddate
FROM v_tblTimeCard
WHERE convert(date, TimeCard_CreatedDate) = dateadd(day,-1, cast(getdate() as date))
group by
userfullname,
USERs_ID,
timecard_date,
TimeCard_CreatedDate

DECLARE @tempMile2 table (USERs_ID int, timecard_date date)
INSERT INTO @tempMile2 (USERs_ID, timecard_date)
SELECT USERs_ID, timecard_date  --add count logic here --timecard entries 1 for day
FROM @tempMile
group by USERs_ID, timecard_date 

select * from dbo.tblMileage left join 
@tempMile2 on tblMileage.Users_ID = @tempMile2.USERs_ID AND tblMileage.DateOfService = @tempMile2.timecard_date
where @tempMile2.TimeCard_Date IS NOT NULL
```

It is only in the last select statement where the @tempMile2 is asking to be declared.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a table variable to qualify a column name.  The table alias cannot start with `@`.  So, try this:

```
select *
from dbo.tblMileage m left join 
     @tempMile2 tm
     on m.Users_ID = tm.USERs_ID and m.DateOfService = tm.timecard_date
where tm.TimeCard_Date IS NOT NULL;
```

Of course, your comparison in the `where` clause implies that the `join` is an inner join, not an outer join, but I didn't make that change.

Comment: Thank you.  I was trying to play with this but was only doing it on one of the table variables.  Thank you!